# Can Ember Handlebars helper observe global object's property?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars helper to show i18n labels. 
I would like this helper to observe a property of a global object and change labels 
dynamically if the value of that property changes. I have been trying something like this but no luck so far:

```
  Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('t', function(key) {
    return I18n.t(key);   
  }, 'App.i18nHelper.locale');
```

Is there any way to make my UI change all i18n labels dynamically?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kinda made it work by copying part of internals of `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper`

```
  Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('t', function(key, options) {
    var currentContext = (options.contexts && options.contexts[0]) || this;
    var view = options.data.view;
    var bindView = view.get('_childViews.lastObject');
    view.registerObserver(currentContext, 'App.i18nHelper.locale', bindView, bindView.rerender);
    return I18n.t(key);
  });
```

Although it is way to hacky, IMHO..

Comment: That looks like a pretty damn good approach to me!  Here's a jsbin with that implementation.  It seems to work like a charm.  http://jsbin.com/ucanam/967/edit

Comment: Dude, seriously, you rock!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work for helpers.  I sorta got this to work by setting an observer on a global property and then forcibly rerendering all views in `Ember.View.views`.  I say "sorta" because it works for the first change of the global var, but then the view goes completely blank on the second change.

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/965/edit

Just click on `foo 0.xxx` to see the change happen.

I'd love to know why it goes blank on the second run...